# Iter function not working while reading csv file

Tags: python, csv, categories

I am trying to complete this part of my program but I am having trouble.

I'm trying to read in the CSV file, tally the total amounts for each budget category, figure out which budget category people spent the most money in and find the total amounts for each year-month (e.g., 2017-05) and determine which person spent the most money on a single item.

This is my code so far:

```
import csv, xml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#read + open
base = open('XML_project.csv').read()
root = base.getroot()

#empty dict variables
baby_count = {}

#baby, outdoors, movies, sports, tools, jewlery, home, grocery, games +
#clothing, music, kids, industrial, shoes, beauty, garden, health, automotive +
#computers, electronics, books, 

for cat1 in base.iter('bab'):
    baby_count = count(baby_count, cat1.attrib['baby'])
    print('baby', cat1, cat1.attrib['baby'])


#to a csv (categories)
#baby
categories = open("categories.csv", mode = 'w', newline = '', encoding="utf-8")
write = csv.writer(categories)

write. writerow(['categories', 'amt'])
for x, z in baby_count.times():
    write.writerow([x,z])

#close
categories.close()
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!  Great job in sharing with us the code you've tried thus far.  Can you tell us where it breaks down and fails for you?

Comment: Also, perhaps you can share your data file, or at least a small portion of it that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `base` is a string. Strings don't have `iter` methods. It's not clear what you think `base.iter('bab')` would return.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `baby_count = count(baby_count, cat1.attrib['baby'])`?